# Life cycle of activity restored with shortcut and restored from list of launched apps

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, lifecycle

I'm writing the contact list application. When user is watching some info about contact, he can leave application.

And there are 2 possible situations of getting back to contact list:

1. User restores contact list from list of launched activities (he will see fragment with user info again)
2. User restores contact list with launcher icon from menu (he will see list with contacts)

Are there any ways (for example extra life cycle methods) to differ this two situations? The same behaviour is in Contacts+ application.

Comment: Just to make sure: You are propertly recreating the state of the activity by using the onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods?

Comment: I don't use them now. The only important information I can save is a list of loaded contacts. But I requery them from ContactsProvider every time I open the list. But why are you asking this?

Comment: It seems like android is recreating the activity when opening it via the launcher icon. Try implementing both methods and see if they are called when opening via launcher icon. If they are called store/restore your fragment state in these calls.